# Avoid frequent updates in WPF custom control

Tags: wpf, layout, custom-controls, updates

I am writing a custom control in WPF. The control have several properties that cause update of the control's logical tree. There are several methods of this form:

```
private static void OnXXXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyControl)obj).RebuildTree();
}
```

Suppose the `RebuildTree()` method is very complex and lenghty and if users changes several properties, this method is called several times causing application slowdown and hanging.

I would like to introduce something like `BeginUpdate()` and `EndUpdate()` methods in a Windows Forms fashion (to ensure the update is called just once), but this practice is widely disouraged in WPF.

I know the renderer have lower priority and flicker may not appear, but still why to spoil precious running time by calling the same update method multiple times?

**Is there any official best practice on how to make efficient update of multiple dependency properties (without updating the entire control after setting each one)?**

Comment: post the code for the `RebuildTree()` method. Also, what does your custom control do?

Comment: @HighCore The method creates a complex 3D model (lots of points), then creates several controls each with a custom shader effect. I do not have a complete code but I would like to resolve this general problem (e.g. imagine the method creates 1 000 controls every time it is called). I would like the application to show only final results to the user after all properties are set, not intermediate steps and all the stuff that should happen "under the hood".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set a flag when any of these properties change, and have the refresh method queued to the Dispatcher only once.

```
private static void OnXXXPropertyChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ((MyControl)obj).NeedsRefresh = true;
    ((MyControl)obj).OnNeedsRefresh();
}

void OnNeedsRefresh()
{
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => 
  {
     if (NeedsRefresh)
     {
        NeedsRefresh = false;
        RebuildTree();
     }
  }),DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);
}
```

This way, all your properties will be updated and THEN the Dispatcher will call your `BeginInvoke`, set the flag to false and refresh only once.

Comment: A clever trick. There is still one drawback: After setting the first property the refresh is done and other refresh calls are avoided because of the `NeedsRefresh` flag. The ideal would be refreshing after the _last_ property is set. Thanks anyway. Maybe there is something like `Delay` property in `Binding` that waits certain amount of time before committing any changes. But if there is no standard method in WPF, I will add custom `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` - this will leave the optimization on the user.

Comment: @Libor `There is still one drawback that after setting the first property the refresh is done and other calls are dropped because of the NeedsRefresh flag` - I don't understand. The `ContextIdle` priority should force all Bindings to update PRIOR to calling the Refresh(). That's what you're looking for right?

Comment: Oh I see. I will try that priority setting.